# Strange month sequence using Spark Sql

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark SQL 2.4.3 and I am trying to create a timeseries of month date like:

`2000-01-01,2000-02-01,2000-03-01,etc`

with date at the first of every month using the following code:

```
scala> spark.sql("select sequence(to_date('2000-01-01'), to_date('2001-01-01'), interval 1 month) as interval_date").show(false)
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|interval_date                                                                                                                                               |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[2000-01-01, 2000-02-01, 2000-03-01, 2000-03-31, 2000-04-30, 2000-05-31, 2000-06-30, 2000-07-31, 2000-08-31, 2000-09-30, 2000-11-01, 2000-12-01, 2001-01-01]|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

but as you can see I get strange dates like:

`2000-03-31, 2000-04-30, 2000-05-31, 2000-06-30, etc`

which is quite unexpected. Any idea to fix the problem?

Comment: I Dont see any issue , I have exeuted in  databricks pyspark 

df=spark.sql("select sequence(to_date('2000-01-01'), to_date('2001-01-01'), interval 1 month) as interval_date")
df.show(truncate=False)

Comment: do u get my same result?

Comment: yes, i am getting as expected, don't know why you are seeding different output

[2000-01-01, 2000-02-01, 2000-03-01, 2000-04-01, 2000-05-01, 2000-06-01, 2000-07-01, 2000-08-01, 2000-09-01, 2000-10-01, 2000-11-01, 2000-12-01, 2001-01-01]

Comment: ok I don't get why it is returning that for me then. Are u using spark 2.4.3?

Comment: No, I am using  Spark  3.0

Comment: not sure then, seems a bug

Comment: @Randomize apparently it is a bug. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-31654
I can't tell what the status is, or how they fixed it. The issue is resolved as "cannot reproduce".

Comment: @kfkhalili thank you seems to be that problem. It is marked as solved in 2.4.4.

Comment: @Randomize Could you find the commit that fixed it?

Comment: @kfkhalili neither https://github.com/apache/spark/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aclosed+ nor per branch 2.4